# Spark Local File Streaming - Fault tolerance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working on an application where every 30sec(can be 5 sec also) some files will be dropped in a file system. I have to read it parse it and push some records to REDIS.

In each file all records are independent and I am not doing any calculation that will require `updateStateByKey`.

My question is if due to some issue (eg: REDIS connection issue, Data issue in a file etc) some file is not processed completely I want to reprocess (say n times) the files again and also keep a track of the files already processed.

For testing purpose I am reading from a local folder. Also I am not sure how to conclude that one file is fully processed and mark it as completed (ie write in a text file or db that this file processed)

```
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("E:\\SampleData\\GG")
val words = lines.map(x=>x.split("_"))
words.foreachRDD(
   x=>  {
     x.foreach(           
       x => {
         var jedis = jPool.getResource();
         try{
          i=i+1
           jedis.set("x"+i+"__"+x(0)+"__"+x(1), x(2))
         }finally{
           jedis.close()
         }
       }
     )
   }
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark has a fault tolerance guide. Read more :

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#fault-tolerance-semantics